# upload files to public firebase storage in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

is there anyway to send files to selected public firebase storage using the bucket url 'gs://...' ? 
I think there is one for Java:
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://my-custom-bucket");
but i can't find any for Ionic

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularfire2.

please see:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

for more details.